# jQuery - Having a DIV autohide at startup safely

Tags: jquery, html

Is it possible to set the CSS properties of a DIV to not initially display, and then have jQuery show it at a later time?

I have some popup bubbles on my website that I do not want to show if JavaScript is disabled.

Currently I have calls to hide all elements when the page loads via jQuery, and only show them when the proper button is clicked.

However, disabling JavaScript will force those bubbles to appear on the page.

If I tweak the display or visibility settings of these divs, it seems that I cannot use jQuery to make them show on the click event.

Is there some manner of autohiding these without breaking jQuery functionality?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just add the css attribute of `display:none` to the divs you want hidden. Then you can use jquery's `.show()` to unhide these divs when you want to show them later.

Comment: i see this now, for some reason i thought it hadn't been working for me previously...may have been a typo....regardless ty!

Answer (score 2):

The jQuery show/hide functions do not work with `visibility`. If you set `display: none`, it should work just fine. If, however, you use `visibility: hidden`, they won't work correctly.